# Explorer (Desktop) Stops Refreshing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, desktop

After using Windows 7 for a while (say, a few hours), Explorer always stops refreshing my desktop, and I have to close it and re-open it. E.g.: When I delete a file, it doesn't seem to go away even though it does; I have to press F5 to refresh the desktop.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: No, its a windows bug, hitting F5 will refresh whatever window is open, sometimes you have to hit F5 several times, welcome to Windows.

Comment: Yeah I suspected it was probably a bug.
And haha I'm not exactly new to Windows (I just thought someone might have a solution for this bug... I've used Windows ever since I was born..) but thank you for the welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having this problem specifically on Windows 7 (and by extension, Vista), then one of the most likely reasons is that the *Windows Management Instrumentation* service is not running. I have experienced this issue on 7 and after some testing, determined that Explorer does not automatically update on file-operations if the service is not running, and that starting it will resolve the issue.

1. Open the *Services* MMC snap-in (`services.msc`)
2. Make sure that *Windows Management Instrumentation* is running (start it if it is not)
3. Make sure it is also set to `Automatic` start-up

(Don’t mix it up with *Windows Management Instrumentation Driver Extensions* which has no impact on this problem.)

Sadly, this does not fix the same problem of Explorer not refreshing on Windows XP. That is a mystery I am still investigating…

Comment: Wow, I'll test this as soon as I can -- I feel you're 100% correct, because I usually set WMI to Manual start... I hope I don't forget about your answer by the time the problem comes up again (I've learned to ignore it...) but I'll test it as soon as it comes up! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the WMI service is one of the ones I stop when trying to strip Windows down to the minimum (in XP, I could get it down to just four services, but in Vista+, it bottoms out at six or seven). Unfortunately it turns out that this is not quite as unnecessary as I thought (though it is still expendable when I am trying to stop everything).

Comment: LOL that's just like what I do! I stop it because I I hate extra processes and I figure if it needs to run then something will start it.

Comment: *> I figure if it needs to run then something will start it.*   Or something will crash and I’ll know it *actually* is required. ☺

Comment: Just thought I'd mention, on Windows 8 right now, my desktop stopped refreshing but WMI was running. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad, maybe it requires some of those extra processes like `wmiprvse.exe` and `wmiapsrv.exe` that keep popping up. I have yet to fully plumb the depths of how Windows (Explorer) works and what is *actually* necessary. And it certainly doesn’t help that they keep changing how things work. `:-/`

Comment: @Mehrdad
Also check my answer below (sorry for necrocommenting) :)

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this problem deleting iconcache.db file.

1. Open your task manager and kill the explorer process
2. Then choose **File**->**New Task (Run)**, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In Command Prompt, use the following commands:

```
CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
DEL IconCache.db /a
EXIT
```

And then use Task Manager to open application **explorer.exe**

I you feel lazy / not comfortable with this I've written a simple application that takes care of the problem for my friends.

You can download it [here](http://www.davidenastri.it/files/windows-icons-fixer-setup.zip)

If you don't trust it [here](https://github.com/ltpitt/windows-icons-fixer)'s its source code too.

Comment: I haven't encountered the problem for a long time to test this, but +1 thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem corrects itself if I close all instances of Windows Explorer.  Upon reopening Explorer, everything refreshes correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This problem dates back to Vista, according to Microsoft.com webpages. And over the years, MS just responds the same way: try safe mode, SFC, etc, to identify a non-Microsoft culprit. Well, I used XP Pro for many years, only upgrading in July 2012, to Win7. And this problem never ever occurred on XP Pro. It's very clearly a Microsoft Windows problem. And if it's triggered by a variety of other software, then it's still a Windows problem, since the purpose of Windows to provide a system where other software and hardware can operate.

I tried many of the proposed solutions from various forum threads -- some going for 40+ pages. Nothing has worked. I've not edited my registry because that doesn't appear successful from what I've read, and it would probably require a restart to implement, and then my problem might disappear for a while.

Anyway, I have xplorer2 pro, which cost me $30 for a lifetime of version upgrades. I used it on XP Pro (after I suffered explorer & drwatson crashes in XP :( -- but the good news is that xplorer2 pro is a superb product w/ an unbelievably detailed manual. In my own use, I've barely scratched the surface of what it can do, but it serves me well, and I presume it will solve this problem. (My only gripe w/ xplorer2 is the lack of an undo. It does have a menu command to go to the last drop target, for drag-n-drop errors, but an undo would be better, esp since the recycle bin misses things sometimes ..and the old norton protected bin is no longer an option -- though I used it as long as I could, disabling/deleting everything else in the utilities suite.)

Sorry, I do digress. Anyhow, I've no vested interest, but I do encourage people to try xplorer2 -- the free version or the Pro version. A no-registry portable edition is available too. And for the other end, if you look, you'll find a instructions for editing the registry so xplorer2 replaces explorer in nearly every instance where explorer would otherwise appear (save as dialogs & the like excepted).

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for this behavior.

One case is that of a badly-written (de)installation program which creates or deletes icons but doesn't refresh the desktop. As the desktop doesn't always auto-refresh, nicely-written installers do the F5 for you.

A second case is that of an installed product that interferes with the desktop refresh, for example TeraCopy in [this thread](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/9403-no-desktop-refresh.html#post65231). You might try to remember which product you have called for the first time just before this happened.

A third and more remote possibility is a bug in the video driver. Ensure that you have the latest version from the manufacturer's website.

**EDIT**

If the problem is Explorer rather than only the desktop, this is a problem that is reported in Windows since XP and until today. Many remedies have been suggested, which worked for some people. Here are some of them:

1. Ensure that the antivirus isn't the cause
2. Regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Update`, UpdateMode entry, and change the value of the last digit from 1 to either 2 or 7.
3. Regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop,` right-click, New Binary Value, rename to `ExplorerRefreshOnRename`, double-click and change the value to "0001", press OK.
4. At the end of this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/09fd46ff-65f1-4fa7-ae2d-9f3b2644fad6), a registry update is suggested (create first a system restore point).
5. Another suggestion from the same thread is to regedit to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance` and set `DontRefresh` to 0.

Comment: Huh... unfortunately I don't think any of these are the cause, but thank you for your reply!

Comment: Could you then describe which desktop changes are done by which products?

Comment: It's Explorer: I rename a file, but it doesn't refresh (the old name stays). It's obviously renamed, though, since if I try moving it, it says it can't find the item anymore.

Comment: I added some more stuff for Explorer on this well-known problem.

Comment: *> Regedit to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Update, UpdateMode entry, and change the value of the last digit from 1 to either 2 or 7.*   Not only does that not fix it, but it also creates [an Event Log error entry](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showpost.php?p=1296322&postcount=4) on *every* boot—for obvious reasons. Also, `7` is not even [a valid value](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168231/en-us) for it.     Unfortunately, `ExplorerRefreshOnRename` and `DontRefresh ` don’t fix it either. `:-(`

Answer (score 1):

I love all the posts suggesting DontRefresh in the Registry.  Don Quixote would be proud!

Forgot where I found this but it does work for Explorer refresh and Desktop Icons issues:

```
@ ECHO off
Echo Run this if your Taskbar Icons look like blank rectangles
or your Explorer folders / Desktop does not auto-refresh.
Echo Tested for Win XP, Win7 and Server 2003/2010
Echo *****  Use at your own risk. *****
Echo Hit the  key to continue
Echo or the  and  keys to stop
REM  stop windows explorer desktop
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f"
REM  Change to your profile's application data folder
CD %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local
REM change the permissions of the icon cache so we can see it
attrib -h IconCache.db
REM delete the corrupt icon cache
del IconCache.db
REM restart explorer which will rebuild the icon cache correctly
Echo If this did not work you may have bigger problems like a bad hard drive, corrupt registry or a virus.
Echo All Done!
Echo You may need to manually close this window now
call explorer.exe
```