# Files don't disappear after being deleted unless Explorer window is refreshed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Seemingly at random, deleting files from Windows Explorer in Windows 7 does not cause the deleted files to disappear unless the window is refreshed.  This appears to be a well-known issue according to [this Google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows+7+deleted+files+don%27t+disappear&oq=windows+7+fiels+don%27t+delete&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i22i10i30j0i8i13i10i30j0i8i13i30.880.5475.0.6793.28.26.0.1.1.1.235.3039.8j17j1.26.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.FmpjSzUu_NU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.eWU&fp=1ac0351f69ead915&biw=1135&bih=740).

However, if you browse through the links, you will notice that they lead to discussions lasting up to 8 pages consisting of almost nothing but newbies chiming in with *has anyone found the answer to this yet* and *none of these solutions worked for me*?  Honestly, I don't have it in me to spend a couple hours paging through discussion threads and trying every single solution that is suggested like *edit the registry and reboot* or *turn off these Microsoft services and reboot*, so I come to the experts of SE to see if someone can give the world the one solution to this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explorer (Desktop) Stops Refreshing](http://superuser.com/questions/228363/explorer-desktop-stops-refreshing) or [explorer does not auto-refresh](http://superuser.com/questions/390030/explorer-does-not-auto-refresh)

Comment: Also have a look at [this Microsoft forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-does-not-refresh-folder-views/9d1ede23-2666-4951-b3b9-b6c1ce3d1ebf) (as well as [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/8afb8b65-900c-4f42-b1df-3c2394417b6e)).

Answer (score 0):

Open up regedit and take a look at the hives:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance

In there you should find a key for "DontRefresh". If the value is 1, then change it to 0. You also did not specify whether you're on a 32 or 64bit version of Windows. The given paths are for 64-bit Windows, but should you be on 32-bit, just omit the "Wow6432Node" portions of each path. That's the solution I had work for me the last time I had this issue, but sadly it doesn't seem to guarantee a resolve for everyone.